# Haskell: Get a Get monad and also return polymorphism over infinite types

Tags: haskell, serialization

I apologize in advance if the following is based on a misunderstanding on my part. I couldn't find the answers I needed anywhere.

I am implementing a program that reads serialized objects from a file, using lazy evaluation all throughout. I am parsing the file by first reading it in as a single Lazy ByteString and then parsing it using the Get Monad. Within the file, there is one point where type descriptors are stored, and another point where data is storied. Type descriptors tell me how data is to be interpreted and which type it eventually has, and that type can take nested forms; Double or [[Word8]] are two possibilities.

Now, the idea to do this that I came up with (and which briefly sounded incredibly elegant) is the following: what if the method (that parses the type descriptor) creates – but not runs – a Get Monad that can then *later* be run with the ByteString that holds the data?

That would necessitate a method such as this:

```
parseTypeDescriptor :: Get (Get a)
```

Where a is the same type that the descriptor describes (meaning it can take nested forms). Here are some parts of the code right now:

```
parseTypeDescriptor :: Get (Get a)
-- first part of the type descriptor is an id (Word8) that implies a type
parseTypeDescriptor = getWord8 >>= go
   where go 0 = return getWord8
         go 1 = return getWord16be
         go 2 = return getWord32be
                 ...
         -- id 5 indicates that the type is an array
         -- this means two more values are coming;
         -- the first indicates the array's length, the second its type
         go 5 = do n      <- getWord8
                   action <- parseTypeDescriptor
                   return $ -- TODO --
```

The type of 'action' should be 'Get a'. What I need at -- TODO -- is to construct a value that executes action n times, puts those values in an array, and puts a Get around that array.

Example: if action = getWord16be and n = 2; then TODO ought to be equivalent to this:

```
TODO :: Get [a]
TODO = do x <- getWord16be
          y <- getWord16be
          return [x,y]
```

---

I have 3 problems with all this:

1. I don't know what code at -- TODO -- does what I want
2. The compiler tells me the root method (parseTypeDescriptors) can't
   return more than one type. If it returns Get (Get Word8) it can't
   also return Get (Get [Word8])
3. I am not sure if, when the Top-level Get is run, it can be avoided
   that the Gets it creates are also run

I'm beginning to suspect that this is actually impossible to do, but I hope I'm wrong-- and that my explanation was understandable.

Comment: I fear that the correct type for this would something like `Get (exists a. Get a)`, using existential rather than universal quantification (and let's ignore the predicativity issues for now...). This also means that this parser would not offer any static guarantee about the type of the output, and as such its result would be practically unusable. I'd make the parser return something in a large sum, or at worst return `Dynamic`. As such it seems unfeasible.

Comment: Apart from the details with existentials that others have pointed out, your intuition that `Get (Get a)` gives you context-sensitivity is right. It’s basically the reason `Monad` is equipped with `join :: m (m a) -> m a`: `Monad` describes computations that can depend on previous results—unlike, say, `Applicative`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't really returning something polymorphic (*universally quantified*) there – in fact you're always returning a concrete type `Get A`, but it will only be decided at runtime which it is. This is called [existential quantification](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type). Haskell98 didn't have any such thing, but you can do it with generalised algebraic data types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data GetSomething where
   GetSomething :: Get a -> GetSomething

parseTypeDescriptor :: Get GetSomething
-- first part of the type descriptor is an id (Word8) that implies a type
parseTypeDescriptor = getWord8 >>= go
   where go 0 = return $ GetSomething getWord8
         go 1 = return $ GetSomething getWord16be
         go 2 = return $ GetSomething getWord32be
```

So far so good... trouble is, there's not really anything useful you can do with `GetSomething`, because there's no way to know what type it actually yields (it's hidden within the GADT). There are ways to overcome this – for instance, if all the parsed types belong to a common type class, you can add it as a constraint:

```
data GetSomething where
   GetSomething :: CommonClass a => Get a -> GetSomething
```

This way you will be able to parse values and do something with them even without knowing the exact type.

However, this is probably not the best approach: you'll basically always have to run after the missing type information and hack around to still get stuff done. Existentials are considered a bit of an antipattern in Haskell.

A better solution is likely to put the types in a clear alternative data structure:

```
data GetSomething
   = GetW8 (Get Word8)
   | GetW16 (Get Word16)
   | ...
   | GetList [GetSomething]
```

Then you can simply pattern-match to find out what particular type you have, and because the list of supported types is finite you can be sure you won't run into problems because a type isn't actually supported.